# jQuery and coffee objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to build a js object that represents a combination of HTML components. In the constructor of this object, the id of `div` element should be given as a parameter. My question is why I'm not able to use jQuery methods on when the given string is used as a jQuery selector and selected element is saved as a field of this object.

```js
class Element
  constructor: (id) ->
    @form = $(id)

  addNewClass: (text) ->
    @form.addClass(text)
  
element = new Element '#element'
element.addNewClass 'the_class'
```

```html
<div id='element'></div>
```

P.S: I'm working on ruby on rails environment if this matters

Comment: Looks like jquery is unavailable during call your `Element`. Do you use assets pipeline? Do you define code listed above in view?

Comment: Yes. The `#element` exists `the value of `@form` is `jQuery.fn.init` object but when I try to execute method nothing happen. Nothing changes or error is raised.